# ListView inside ScrollView with Auto Adjust Height

Tags: android, listview, height, scrollview, onmeasure

I try to create a `ListView` Inside `ScrollView` with `EdiText` inside the `ListView`. So I use a Custom method to make my `ListView` NonScrollable.

My ListView Item xml is like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textColor="#222"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title1"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="#727272"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:hint="Note"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:id="@+id/text_note"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Custom method Code is like this:

```
public class NonScrollListView extends ListView {

    public NonScrollListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public NonScrollListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int heightMeasureSpec_custom = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec_custom);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```

The problem is when I make a new line in EditText my listview height is not adjust and make my last Item in ListView disappear.
The Screenshot is like this:

This is what I try to make
[image: Before]

But the result is like this
[image]

I see from here:
[Android: Listview in ScrollView with dynamic height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200009/android-listview-in-scrollview-with-dynamic-height)

It said that Change `ListView` to `LinearLayout`.. Can someone help me how to make that ? I have no idea how to change `ListView` to `LinearLayout`.

And if not have to change to `LinearLayout` is there any way how to adjust the height of my `ListView` so my item will not disappear ?

Need help to solve this.

Comment: can you share the list item's xml view?

Comment: @Ajitha I already add my list items xml, can you help me how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

Try using this method :

```
 public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter(); 
            if (listAdapter == null) {
                // pre-condition
                return;
            }

            int totalHeight = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
                listItem.measure(0, 0);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
```

like `setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listView)`.

Comment: I already try to solution before.. but how to use it when I change my editText ? Have I write this `setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listView)` inside EditText TextWatcher ?

Comment: I already try to put it in `public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)` but still same .. my ListView can adjust the height automatic. Did I put in wrong place ?

Comment: Like what I explain and put my Image at top.. ListView adjust the height automatic wherever I make a new line in my EditText. The Code above not working and can't adjust the height of my listview